# How to improve this query (using table variables or not?)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm having a bit of problems with these tables...

```
TableCost
(
TableCostId int,
Cost numeric,
MonthsId int
)
```

and

```
Taxes
(
Percentt numeric,
MonthsId int
)
```

I have to calculate a new value by getting the biggest `Taxes.MonthsId` that do not exceed the  `TableCost.MonthsId` (for each row).

For example, if I have the following registers:

TableCost:

```
(1,10,1),
(2,5,3),
(3,12,7),
(4,17,8),
(5,22,11)
```

Taxes:

```
(55,1),
(60,2),
(65,6),
(70,10),
(75,12)
```

To calculate the TaxedCost of the

```
first row of the TableCost -> 10*55
Second row -> 5*60
Third row ->12*65
Fourth row -> 17*65
Fifth row -> 22*70
```

The select must return the following fields

```
(Cost,TaxedCost)
```

I've tought of declaring a table variable... storage the Taxes values on it, runs a normal select on the TableCost table and looping each of its rows calculating the TaxedCost after the select.

Any ideas of improve this query?

Comment: Given the data you've specified, you're going to have to run a correlated subquery. Performance is going to suck no matter what you do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a correlated sub query.

```
SELECT Cost, 
       Cost * (SELECT TOP 1 Percentt 
               FROM   Taxes t 
               WHERE  t.MonthsId <= tc.MonthsId 
               ORDER  BY t.MonthsId DESC) AS TaxedCost 
FROM   TableCost tc
```

You may well get a more efficient plan though if you simply fill in the gaps in your `Taxes` table so you can do a straight forward join on `MonthsId`. At least that should allow the optimiser to consider something other than nested loops.

Comment: +1 - Just a question out of curiosity, could this be done with an `OUTER APPLY` instead?, would it make any difference?.

Comment: @Lamak - Yes. AFAIK `OUTER APPLY` would likely give the same plan though in this case.